# a way to turn off report generation for canoo webtest

Tags: report, webtest, canoo, canoo-webtest

I am running canoo webtest against a suite with over 1000 tests. The entire process is taking a little longer than I would like. My question is: Is there a way to turn off the html report generation completely? Or a way to write the report for only the test failures?

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never... You can turn off html report generation. You cannot only generate the html report for failures, unfortunately.

If you edit webtest.xml, you can change the wt.config.saveresponse default property to false.

```
<property name="wt.config.saveresponse" value="false"/>
```

Alternatively, I prefer put *wt.config.saveresponse=false* in a canoo.properties file and import the properties file in the **build.xml** of my canoo test dir by using

```
<property file="../canoo.properties" />
```

In that way it is easy to switch saving results on and off to debug issues.

Regards,
SazD

Comment: thanks that did work this morning - although it didn't speed up the test execution time as much as I thought it would have :(